# Android apk install - Parsing package error and mount /data/data... path

Tags: android, apk

I am doing a small application for a private circulation so that I do not use google play to install and update the app.

In my MainActivity, I will check whether app updation found or not via an api. If any update found my app download the updated apk file into **download** folder on the SDCard and install by:

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(destination)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

it works fine, but my problem is users can get the apk file in the **download** folder. So that I decided to download the file into **/data/data/com.xxx.aaa**. This idea, download the file into the **/data...** path. But I could not be installed the apk file. I make sure the apk file is present into the `download folder` by the following code:

```
if(new File(destination).exists()){
  // apk file is present into download folder.
}
```

my method showing **Parsing Error** as below:

[image]

My Questions is:

How can I get install the updated apk file from the /data.... path?

I guess root privilege is the problem to install apk.
please help me.

**Edited question:-**
To get root access my application I run the following command:

```
try {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
}
```

after executing this command I can list /data/data/com.xxx.aaa path. and I have verified my downloaded apk file is presented here.

To install the apk, as told in the comment I run **mount** command in various option but no luck. I get **Parsing error** as shown in the figure.

I have tried the  **mount** in the following ways:

```
1) mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
2) mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /data/data.com.xxx.aaa/appinfo.apk
3) mount
4) mount /system
```

I do not know the right way to mount /data/data/.... path. How to mount the /data/data/.... path.
please help me.

Comment: Yes, you required root access to add any content to /data/data folder, and also need mount command to mount /data folder in root account.

Comment: @VISHAL VIRADIA, Sorry for the delay, How to create my app with root access? or Is there any way in Google Play for private circulation?
thanks.

Comment: i add process bellow, if you want more help then please tell me, thanks.

Comment: VISHAL is mistaken, you do not need to remount anything to write to the /data partition.  That only concerns writing to /system, when trying to install fake system apps, which is not what you are doing here.  Overall though, this whole idea is a poor one - and realize that any user with a rooted device on which your app could run, is also a user who can get your apk even once it is installed!

Answer (score 1):

**To List Files From /data/app/**

```
[1] su

[2] ls /data/app/
```

**To get apk from "/data/app/" folder**

```
# ls /data/app/
```

i am getting following apk list

com.android.vending-1.apk

com.google.android.gms-1.apk

com.noshufou.android.su-1.apk

com.corusen.accupedo.te-1.zip

com.microsoft.office.lync-1.apk

com.okythoos.android.tdmpro-1.apk

com.devindia.acr-1.apk

for example i want to get "com.android.vending-1.apk" out to /sdcard

```
[1] su

[2] cat /data/app/com.android.vending-1.apk > /sdcard/com.android.vending-1.apk

[3] adb pull /sdcard/com.android.vending-1.apk /path-to-your-folder/
```

**To Run application as system app**

```
[1] adb push your-app.apk /sdcard/

[2] adb shell

[3] su

[4] mount -o remount,rw /system

[5] cat /sdcard/your-app.apk > /system/app/your-app.apk

[6] chmod 0644 /system/app/your-app.apk
```

**Run Command As Root User, From Your Android Code :**

for example if you want to run command "chmod 0644 /system/app/your-app.apk" form root user

**Example Steps :**

```
[1] Execute From Computer
adb push your-app.apk /sdcard/

[2] Execute From Android Code
Exec_SU("mount -o remount,rw /system");
Exec_SU("cat /sdcard/your-app.apk > /system/app/your-app.apk");
Exec_SU("chmod 0644 /system/app/your-app.apk");
```

Here is implementation of above function "Exec_SU" :

```
    public static void Exec_SU(String str_command) 
    { 
        // working well
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
        Process proc = null; 
        OutputStreamWriter osw = null;    
        StringBuilder sbstdOut = new StringBuilder();   
        sbstdErr = new StringBuilder();

        String command=str_command;

        try { 
            // Run Script    
            proc = runtime.exec("su");   
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());  
            osw.write(command);   
            osw.flush();     
            osw.close();     
            } catch (IOException ex) { 
                ex.printStackTrace();   
                } finally {       
                    if (osw != null) {     
                        try {      
                            osw.close();   
                            } catch (IOException e) { 
                                e.printStackTrace(); 
                                }      
                            }    
                    }   
                try {     
                    if (proc != null)    
                        proc.waitFor();  
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                        }   

    }
```

i think this will helpful to you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i let you know after implement.

Comment: Hi, i got the following error: 
Error running exec(). Command: [adb, push, /data/data/com.xxx.aaa/appinfo.apk, /sdcard/] Working Directory: null Environment: null

To execute this command Should my device has root access or my application has root access?. To get root i am running "su" command on my code.
please help me.

I am running the commands in my code.

Comment: i add your required code in above my answer, please check it and give me your feedback, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your great help, But i got same parsing package problem. i  execute the commands 1 to 6 as given order by you with Exec_SU(). The command chmod command i tried 777 permission but no luck. 

The first command i give my full path where your.apk like this 
adb push /data/data/com.xxx.aaa/appinfo.apk.

Please help me. This is very important otherwise any other way to keep apk file from user?

Comment: All the commands executed without error. after i checked into /system/app folder , there is no appinfo.apk file.

Comment: "adb push /data/data/com.xxx.aaa/appinfo.apk" will nor execute from Exec_SU() function. because you are already in adb shell. You have to copy appinfo.apk to your sdcard using this command "cat /sdcard/appinfo.apk > //data/data/com.xxx.aaa/appinfo.apk" from Exec_SU() .

Comment: i added Example Steps for your android code in my above answer, please try and tell me if any problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for great help and sorry for delay, i am in another task so that i couldn't update you. i will update you in a week.